Import gradle plugin from Sonatype repository
I've uploaded my open source project to Sonatype repository. Now I want to add my plugin to new project like this:
build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("contractor-plugin") version "1.0.0"
}

settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            setUrl("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases")
        }
    }
}

I already added my project to Sonatype. Whole configuration is under this link. It automatically fills pom data, creates sources, jar and so on.
All I've got is message like Plugin [id: 'contractor-plugin', version: '1.0.0'] was not found in any of the following sources. When I build it locally it works fine, probably because publishToMavenLocal generate another folder with *.plugin extension, which is probably plugin marker artifact, but I'm using java-gradle-plugin inside my project.
What I need to do to let it work?

Have you published the plugin? That's the key code to be looking at.

Plugin is published in public Sonatype repository. It can be easly downloaded by implementation, but not as a plugin.

Then you've not published correctly in Gradle plugin format

@SimonJacobs all right, so what's the correct format? here I defined gradlePlugin and publishing section with all details and here is my released plugin

Please put the relevant details in a question

@SimonJacobs Sure, I did it

The plugin ID also contains the group ID.
You're setting it in the code here:
id = "$group.contractor-plugin"

So the correct way to apply it would be like this:
plugins {
    id("com.miquido.contractor-plugin") version "1.0.1"
}


The cause was not publishing all files to the remote repository. Simply typing gradle clean publish did the work properly, because instead of sending jar with sources, it should send also marker plugin definition.
Another fault was not adding "group" like @fxshlein mentioned. After that I was able to see two artifacts.
